# How can I create a grid that is a rectangle in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, grids

How can I create a grid that is 150x50 pixels? The grid feature in Filters->Renderer->Pattern->Grid does not let me create grids other than a square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click on the chain link icon (shown circled in red below) to break the link between the width and height, to be able to enter different values.

[image]